# ERROR in No files matching 'xxx.js' were found

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I am developing a small project using webpack, React.js with Visual Studio. After renaming, deleting and creating a certain file with the name xxx.js I have got an error:

```
ERROR in No files matching 'C:\MyPath\src\ViewLayer\xxx.js' were found.
Failed to compile.
No issues found.
```

What could be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I discovered that the entry `C:\MyPath\src\ViewLayer\xxx.js` exists in `C:\MyPath\public\stats.json`. I removed this file and restarted the project with regular:

```
npm start
```

It has worked. The error disappeared. Now I have:

```
Compiled successfully.
No issues found.
```

It is a vierd world :-)